# How to combine python asyncio with threads?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I have successfully built a [RESTful microservice](https://github.com/fxstein/SentientHome/blob/develop/engine/event.engine.py) with Python asyncio and aiohttp that listens to a POST event to collect realtime events from various feeders.

It then builds an in-memory structure to cache the last 24h of events in a nested defaultdict/deque structure.

Now I would like to periodically checkpoint that structure to disc, preferably using pickle.

Since the memory structure can be >100MB I would like to avoid holding up my incoming event processing for the time it takes to checkpoint the structure.

I'd rather create a snapshot copy (e.g. deepcopy) of the structure and then take my time to write it to disk and repeat on a preset time interval.

I have been searching for examples on how to combine threads (and is a thread even the best solution for this?) and asyncio for that purpose but could not find something that would help me.

Any pointers to get started are much appreciated!

Comment: I have used dano's suggestions and built a very simple multi threaded setup that checkpoints the in-memory event store every 60 seconds to disk. Here is a link to the git repo file that contains the entire logic: https://github.com/fxstein/SentientHome/blob/master/engine/event.engine.py

Answer (score 95, accepted):

It's pretty simple to delegate a method to a thread or sub-process using [`BaseEventLoop.run_in_executor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.BaseEventLoop.run_in_executor):

```
import asyncio
import time
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

def cpu_bound_operation(x):
    time.sleep(x) # This is some operation that is CPU-bound

@asyncio.coroutine
def main():
    # Run cpu_bound_operation in the ProcessPoolExecutor
    # This will make your coroutine block, but won't block
    # the event loop; other coroutines can run in meantime.
    yield from loop.run_in_executor(p, cpu_bound_operation, 5)


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
p = ProcessPoolExecutor(2) # Create a ProcessPool with 2 processes
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

As for whether to use a `ProcessPoolExecutor` or `ThreadPoolExecutor`, that's kind of hard to say; pickling a large object will definitely eat some CPU cycles, which initially would make you think `ProcessPoolExecutor` is the way to go. However, passing your 100MB object to a `Process` in the pool would require pickling the instance in your main process, sending the bytes to the child process via IPC, unpickling it in the child, and then pickling it *again* so you can write it to disk. Given that, my guess is the pickling/unpickling overhead will be large enough that you're better off using a `ThreadPoolExecutor`, even though you're going to take a performance hit because of the GIL.

That said, it's very simple to test both ways and find out for sure, so you might as well do that.

Comment: Thank you dano! This was a lot easier after all. You are correct I took the path of using ThreadPoolExecutor and it works fine. Writing checkpoints ever 60 sec now without holding up any of the event processing.

Answer (score 16):

I also used `run_in_executor`, but I found this function kinda gross under most circumstances, since it requires `partial()` for keyword args and I'm never calling it with anything other than a single executor and the default event loop. So I made a convenience wrapper around it with sensible defaults and automatic keyword argument handling.

```
from time import sleep
import asyncio as aio
loop = aio.get_event_loop()

class Executor:
    """In most cases, you can just use the 'execute' instance as a
    function, i.e. y = await execute(f, a, b, k=c) => run f(a, b, k=c) in
    the executor, assign result to y. The defaults can be changed, though,
    with your own instantiation of Executor, i.e. execute =
    Executor(nthreads=4)"""
    def __init__(self, loop=loop, nthreads=1):
        from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
        self._ex = ThreadPoolExecutor(nthreads)
        self._loop = loop
    def __call__(self, f, *args, **kw):
        from functools import partial
        return self._loop.run_in_executor(self._ex, partial(f, *args, **kw))
execute = Executor()

...

def cpu_bound_operation(t, alpha=30):
    sleep(t)
    return 20*alpha

async def main():
    y = await execute(cpu_bound_operation, 5, alpha=-2)

loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Answer (score 7):

Another alternative is to use [`loop.call_soon_threadsafe`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.call_soon_threadsafe) along with an [`asyncio.Queue`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-queue.html#asyncio.Queue) as the intermediate channel of communication.

The current documentation for Python 3 also has a section on [Developing with asyncio - Concurrency and Multithreading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-dev.html#asyncio-multithreading):

```py
import asyncio

# This method represents your blocking code
def blocking(loop, queue):
    import time
    while True:
        loop.call_soon_threadsafe(queue.put_nowait, 'Blocking A')
        time.sleep(2)
        loop.call_soon_threadsafe(queue.put_nowait, 'Blocking B')
        time.sleep(2)

# This method represents your async code
async def nonblocking(queue):
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    while True:
        queue.put_nowait('Non-blocking A')
        await asyncio.sleep(2)
        queue.put_nowait('Non-blocking B')
        await asyncio.sleep(2)

# The main sets up the queue as the communication channel and synchronizes them
async def main():
    queue = asyncio.Queue()
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()

    blocking_fut = loop.run_in_executor(None, blocking, loop, queue)
    nonblocking_task = loop.create_task(nonblocking(queue))

    running = True  # use whatever exit condition
    while running:
        # Get messages from both blocking and non-blocking in parallel
        message = await queue.get()
        # You could send any messages, and do anything you want with them
        print(message)

asyncio.run(main())
```

How to [send asyncio tasks to loop running in other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32059732/) may also help you.

If you need a more "powerful" example, check out my [Wrapper to launch async tasks from threaded code](https://gist.github.com/Lonami/3f79ed774d2e0100ded5b171a47f2caf). It will handle the thread safety part for you (for the most part) and let you do things like this:

```
# See https://gist.github.com/Lonami/3f79ed774d2e0100ded5b171a47f2caf for the full example

async def async_main(queue):
    # your async code can go here
    while True:
        command = await queue.get()
        if command.id == 'print':
            print('Hello from async!')
        elif command.id == 'double':
            await queue.put(command.data * 2)

with LaunchAsync(async_main) as queue:
    # your threaded code can go here
    queue.put(Command('print'))
    queue.put(Command('double', 7))
    response = queue.get(timeout=1)
    print('The result of doubling 7 is', response)
```

Comment: The only way you interact with `queue` from another thread is through [`loop.call_soon_threadsafe`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.call_soon_threadsafe), which "Must be used to schedule callbacks *from another thread*." As I understand it, this is the safe way to do it, but I may be misunderstanding the documentation.

Comment: Could someone please explain why if we comment out all three `await asyncio.sleep()` function executions in `async def nonblocking(queue)`, the code stops working as expected?

Comment: If there are no `await`, the function effectively becomes blocking. `await` is needed so that the `asyncio` event loop can resume control (the function is paused in the `await` points, letting it do other work, before getting back to it; it literally "returns" at that point but gets back to it later).

Comment: Thank you, I am aware of that. However, I have two follow up questions: 1. Isn't `queue.put_nowait('Non-blocking A')` supposed to be non-blocking, since it's a "nowait" version of `put`? 2. I tried doing `await queue.put_nowait('Non-blocking A')` but that didn't make a difference.

Comment: `put` is a coroutine (needs to be `await`-ed) which blocks (yields control) until there's free space in the queue to put the item. `put_nowait` is not a coroutine (does not use `await`) and will instead raise an error if the queue is not full. If `nonblocking` never sleeps or yields, it will not give a chance for other code to run. You can use `await asyncio.sleep(0)` to force a yield without sleeping.