# Why coroutines cannot be used with run_in_executor?

Tags: python-3.x, async-await, python-multithreading, python-asyncio

I want to run a service that requests urls using coroutines and multithread. However I cannot pass coroutines to the workers in the executor. See the code below for a minimal example of this issue:

```
import time
import asyncio
import concurrent.futures

EXECUTOR = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5)

async def async_request(loop):
    await asyncio.sleep(3)

def sync_request(_):
    time.sleep(3)

async def main(loop):
    futures = [loop.run_in_executor(EXECUTOR, async_request,loop) 
               for x in range(10)]

    await asyncio.wait(futures)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main(loop))
```

Resulting in the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "co_test.py", line 17, in <module>
    loop.run_until_complete(main(loop))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/base_events.py", line 387, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/futures.py", line 274, in result
    raise self._exception
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/tasks.py", line 239, in _step
    result = coro.send(None)
  File "co_test.py", line 10, in main
    futures = [loop.run_in_executor(EXECUTOR, req,loop) for x in range(10)]
  File "co_test.py", line 10, in <listcomp>
    futures = [loop.run_in_executor(EXECUTOR, req,loop) for x in range(10)]
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/base_events.py", line 541, in run_in_executor
    raise TypeError("coroutines cannot be used with run_in_executor()")
TypeError: coroutines cannot be used with run_in_executor()
```

I know that I could use `sync_request` funcion instead of `async_request`, in this case I would have coroutines by means of sending the blocking function to another thread.

I also know I could call `async_request` ten times in the event loop. Something like in the code below:

```
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
futures = [async_request(loop) for i in range(10)]
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(futures))
```

But in this case I would be using a single thread.

How could I use both scenarios, the coroutines working within multithreads? As you can see by the code, I am passing (and not using) the `pool` to the `async_request` in the hopes I can code something that tells the worker to make a future, send it to the pool and asynchronously (freeing the worker) waits for the result.

The reason I want to do that is to make the application scalable. Is it an unnecessary step? Should I simply have a thread per url and that is it? Something like:

```
LEN = len(list_of_urls)
EXECUTOR = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=LEN)
```

is good enough?

Comment: I'm not really sure why you'd want to do this. You're effectively going to be running a unique loop for each coroutine, which defeats the whole purpose of using an event loop. You should either stick to asyncio, stick to threads, or, if you feel that neither of those is adequate for some reason, try multiprocessing.

Answer (score 34):

You have to create and set a new event loop in the thread context in order to run coroutines:

```
import asyncio
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor


def run(corofn, *args):
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    try:
        coro = corofn(*args)
        asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
        return loop.run_until_complete(coro)
    finally:
        loop.close()


async def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5)
    futures = [
        loop.run_in_executor(executor, run, asyncio.sleep, 1, x)
        for x in range(10)]
    print(await asyncio.gather(*futures))
    # Prints: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Comment: I don't think this reply do what I want. It still takes 2 seconds to run this. I was expecting all the threads to share the same event pool. Maybe I was not clear in my question.

Comment: @zeh The event loop is meant to be thread-specific, since `asyncio` is about cooperative multitasking (as opposed to preemptive multitasking, like the threading model). The loop takes care of switching context between the different tasks, so that only one of them is running at a time. Using threads would defeat this purpose.

Comment: I think there should be a loop for each thread where mulitple coroutines can be executed on like so:
`futures = [asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(corofn(t, ix), loops[i]) for ix in x]`

where i is the thread number. Maybe we can get a working example for this.
There is also an interesting topic here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32059732/send-asyncio-tasks-to-loop-running-in-other-thread

Comment: Well, 5 threads will run and block on `loop.run_until_complete(coro)`. Only when they complete, the 5 threads will execute the next batch of `run_until_complete`

Answer (score 7):

From what I understood from the question, you are trying to use each thread to:

- trigger a coroutine execution
- be free to receive more coroutines to trigger
- wait everything to end in an asynchronous way

However, as soon as you call the loop (be it the main or a new loop) to wait for results, it blocks the thread waiting.

And, by using run_in_executor with a bunch of sync functions, the thread doesn't actually know if there are more coroutines to dispatch in one go before reaching the point where it waits the loop.

I think that if you want to dispatch a bunch of coroutines in such a way as to each thread manage its own group of coroutines in its own event loop, the following code achieved the 1 second total time, multithreaded wait for 10 async sleeps of 1 second.

```
import asyncio
import threading
from asyncio import AbstractEventLoop
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from time import perf_counter
from typing import Dict, Set

import _asyncio

event_loops_for_each_thread: Dict[int, AbstractEventLoop] = {}


def run(corofn, *args):
    curr_thread_id = threading.current_thread().ident

    if curr_thread_id not in event_loops_for_each_thread:
        event_loops_for_each_thread[curr_thread_id] = asyncio.new_event_loop()

    thread_loop = event_loops_for_each_thread[curr_thread_id]
    coro = corofn(*args)
    return thread_loop.create_task(coro)


async def async_gather_tasks(all_tasks: Set[_asyncio.Task]):
    return await asyncio.gather(*all_tasks)


def wait_loops():
    # each thread will block waiting all async calls of its specific async loop
    curr_thread_id = threading.current_thread().ident
    threads_event_loop = event_loops_for_each_thread[curr_thread_id]
    
    # I print the following to prove that each thread is waiting its loop
    print(f'Thread {curr_thread_id} will wait its tasks.')
    return threads_event_loop.run_until_complete(async_gather_tasks(asyncio.all_tasks(threads_event_loop)))


async def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    max_workers = 5
    executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=max_workers)

    # dispatching async tasks for each thread.
    futures = [
        loop.run_in_executor(executor, run, asyncio.sleep, 1, x)
        for x in range(10)]

    # waiting the threads finish dispatching the async executions to its own event loops
    await asyncio.wait(futures)

    # at this point the async events were dispatched to each thread event loop

    # in the lines below, you tell each worker thread to wait all its async tasks completion.
    futures = [
        loop.run_in_executor(executor, wait_loops)
        for _ in range(max_workers)
    ]
    
    print(await asyncio.gather(*futures))
    # it will print something like:
    # [[1, 8], [0], [6, 3, 9, 7], [4], [2, 5]]
    # each sub-set is the result of the tasks of a thread
    # it is non-deterministic, so it will return a diferent array of arrays each time you run.


if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    start = perf_counter()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
    end = perf_counter()
    duration_s = end - start
    # the print below proves that all threads are waiting its tasks asynchronously
    print(f'duration_s={duration_s:.3f}')
```

Comment: Wow, amazing understanding of how asyncio facilities can be used!. I think your answer should be chosen as the accepted answer. I did a similar exercise recently, [see here](https://lazeecoder.medium.com/speeding-up-s3-processing-part-3-9a7e692209cd) , but your solution is more precise than mine

Comment: Not sure but using the above sometimes raises a key error <wrt this threads_event_loop>
`threads_event_loop = event_loops_for_each_thread[curr_thread_id] KeyError: 1231451` and sometimes it runs within 1 sec..

Comment: Hm I can't reproduce that here. Probably OS and/or python version related stuff. This example I ran here on Windows. The threading identification details may differ, so you could try other ways to identify the thread at the dictionary of event loops by threads ('name' perhaps?).

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to write a similar answer to [Tonsic's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63106889) on how `asyncio` should actually be used in this situation, but much more succinctly (using some newer `asyncio` features as well).

What you're really looking for in this case `asyncio.gather`, which let's you run many coroutines concurrently.

From your example, it should thus become:

```py
async def async_request():
    await asyncio.sleep(3)

async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(*[async_request() for _ in range(10)])
```

Now when we time it, it takes about 3 seconds, as desired, instead of 30 seconds:

```py
>>> from time import time
>>> start = time()
>>> asyncio.run(main())
>>> time() - start
3.00907039642334
```

Furthermore, on using `concurrent.futures` alongside `asyncio`, you should identify what blocking code needs an executor and only apply it there to turn it into asynchronous code.

```py
async def async_request():
    # The default executor is a `ThreadPoolExecutor`.
    # In python >= 3.9, this can be shortened to `asyncio.to_thread(sync_request)`.
    await asyncio.get_running_loop().run_in_executor(None, sync_request)
```

From that point, you can then manage your executors by treating these as coroutines with `asyncio`, using things like `asyncio.gather`, as originally shown.