# How to get the someone task's return immediately not until all task completed in [asyncio]?

Tags: python, asynchronous, return, python-asyncio

How to get the someone task's return immediately not until all task completed in [asyncio] ?

```
import asyncio
import time

print(f"now: {time.strftime('%X')}")

async def test1():
    print(f"test1 started at {time.strftime('%X')}")
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    with open('test.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write('...')
    return 'end....'

async def test2(num):
    print(f"test2 started at {time.strftime('%X')}")
    return num * num

async def main(num):
    res = await asyncio.gather(test1(), test2(num))
    return res

def my(num):
    return asyncio.run(main(num))[1]

print(my(5))
print(f"all end at {time.strftime('%X')}")
```

From the above code(python 3.7+), I can only get `test2` return after `test1` and `test2` are all completed.

How can I let the `main` function get `test2` return after test2 is completed, instead of waiting until `test1` is completed?, because `test2` is executed more quickly. **And test1 must be executed(generate test.txt file.)**

Than means return (test2's return) to `main` function or `my` function as soon as possible when test1 and test2 is asynchronous.

Comment: So why do you want test1 to run at all?

Comment: @quamrana test1 is an asynchronous function. I just want to simplify it here, and I have edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run a set of awaitables/coroutines until any Future/Task finishes or is canceled - you need [`asyncio.wait`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.wait) coroutine:

```
...
async def main(num):
    done, pending = await asyncio.wait([test1(), test2(num)], 
                                       return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)
    for coro in done:
        return await coro


def my(num):
    return asyncio.run(main(num))


print(my(5))
print(f"all end at {time.strftime('%X')}")
```

**`return_when`** indicates when this function should return

---

The output:

```
now: 18:50:16
test1 started at 18:50:16
test2 started at 18:50:16
25
all end at 18:50:16
```

---

But since you need all coroutines to be completed - use [`asyncio.as_completed`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.as_completed) approach OR print results from `done` set, then - await from `pending` set and change `print(my(5))` to just `my(5)`:

```
...
async def main(num):
    done, pending = await asyncio.wait([test1(), test2(num)],
                                       return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)
    for coro in done:
        print(await coro)
    for coro in pending:
        await coro


def my(num):
    return asyncio.run(main(num))


my(5)
print(f"all end at {time.strftime('%X')}")
```

Comment: I've tried this method, but the disadvantage of `asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED` is the  rest coroutines will be canceled. It is not what I want. And I have edited the question.

Comment: @stackoverflow26, no need to over-complicate things: since you need all coroutines to be completed - print results from `done` set, then  - await from `pending` set

Comment: I wrongly confirmed the answer, the last sentence in my question, I need return(not just print) **test2's return** to `main` function or `my` function, if I use pending in front of done, like `for coro in pending:      await coro for coro in done:    return  coro.result()`, the coro in `done` will wait `coro` in pending completed, but if exchage the order, the `RETURN` keywork will end the main funciton. so, how to return **test2's return** to main function before test1 completed?

Comment: @stackoverflow26, changing your mind **11** hours later was really insidious. Now I feel that I've upvoted the question prematurely.

Comment: @ RomanPerekhrest Sorry, Since yesterday was too late, I did not verify it carefully. it’s my mistake, I cancel the reception, I just hope that you can continue to really help me. I will accept this answer. If you have time and good mood, I hope that you can continue to help me with the problems mentioned later. I am sorry for the disappointment caused to you.

Comment: @stackoverflow26, Ok, it turns out that besides of initiating a set of coroutines and immediately **return** the first completed result, your expectation is to continue running *pending* coroutines in background. But that's **out** of scope of `asyncio` processing as it's running coroutines **concurrently**  within a **single** thread. You could try a workaround with `loop.run_in_executor` like here https://stackoverflow.com/a/46075571/3185459, but that's likely to throw `ValueError: loop argument must agree with Future`.

Comment: @stackoverflow26, you would need to reconsider how do your coroutines conceptually relate to each other , as well as their order, and try to run a functions like `test1` (with blocking I/O operations) in a separate `Thread`

Comment: Yes, it can be solved very easily with a separate thread. I just want to know if I can solve it with async. In addition, thank you again for the my rude cancellation of the answer. Your answer solved my doubts.