# How does `telethon` TelegramClient(loop=loop) works?

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, telethon

I am new to Python and trying to initialize the Telethon Client on start of a Flask app like

```
def telegram_initailize():
    global client
    global loop
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    client = TelegramClient(
        session=MOBILE, api_id=int(API_ID), api_hash=API_HASH, loop=loop
    )
```

And then when a request comes trying to use it as

```
def run_when_request_come():
    global client
    with client:
      # logic here
```

But it errors out to `RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-2 (process_request_thread)`

Shifting the code of `telegram_initialize` inside `run_when_request_come` works well but it will initialize the client and loop everytime the function is executed

Comment: asyncio loops are per-thread. you'd need to create a new loop on every thread, if you need actual help, post a runnable merged minimal code with imports so people can edit it, other than that, use a different framework than flask that is friendlier with asyncio

Answer (score 0):

`TelegramClient`'s `loop` parameter has been deprecated and no longer has any effect. You can read more about this in Python's changelog and deprecation notes in the documentation for `asyncio`.

`telegram_initailize` is correct, but you can only use that client from the same thread. You cannot call `telegram_initailize` from "Thread 1" and use it in "Thread 2". That's not safe, and it will not work.

See [How to combine python asyncio with threads?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28492103/4759433) instead, or consider using an `asyncio` alternative to Flask.